# $U(1)$ instanton number on manifolds without boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

(1) Let us first consider principal $U(1)$ bundle on $4$-dimensional manifold $X_4$ with $A$ the connection and $F(A)$ the curvature and the following index: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{X_4}\text{ch}_2(A)=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_{X_4}F(A)\wedge F(A), 
\end{eqnarray}
which is supposed to take integral number on the manifolds which support a spin structure (so-called spin manifolds).

However, on a general manifold, 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{X_4}\text{ch}_2(A)\in\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2}, 
\end{eqnarray}
the minimum of which can be realized on $X_4=CP^2$. My question is whether we could realize, e.g. $\int_{X_4}\text{ch}_2(A)=1/2$, on (non-orientable) pin manifolds, e.g. $X_4=RP^4$.

(2) In addition, what about the 2-dimensional $X_2$ manifold cases? We can also consider
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{X_2}\text{ch}_2(A)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{X_2}F(A), 
\end{eqnarray}
and whether there is a 2D's analog that $\int_{X_2}\text{ch}_2(A)=1/2$ with some $U(1)$ bundle over a special chosen $X_2$, e.g. $X_2$ non-orientable such as $X_2=RP^2$?

Comment: One potential example on $RP^4$ with a $1/2$ instanton is the $\epsilon\oplus\epsilon$ bundle where $\epsilon$ is the real line bundle which gives a sign change once the orientation flips along a closed path. The "proof" can be found in Witten's paper on parity anomaly on unorientable manifolds. However, there is no $2D$ analog according to this paper again.

Comment: Does the integral even make good sense on non-orientable 4-manifolds as it stands?

Comment: @Tyrone I see and it seems that such an instanton is ill-defined (or vanishes in some sense) on non-orientable manifolds. And a related question: is there any non-orientable (pin-) manifold version of Atiyah-Singer index theorem (since in AS theorem for spin manifolds there exists an instanton number terms).

Comment: @Tyrone For the integration, should we consider the twisted top form or "density" as the integrated form? In this way, the integration can be understood as half of the integration of the orientable covering of $X$ with that density integrated.